# character class range in awk version 3.1.7

Tags: regex, awk, posix, character-class

Unlike `grep` I am not able to define the size/range of digit character class in `awk. Any clue to right direction is appreciated.

```
cat input
1abc
12abc
123abc
1234abc
12345abc
```

In `grep` I can define the size/length  of digit char class

```
grep -P '^\d{3,4}' input #or grep -P '^[[:digit:]]{3,4}' input
123abc
1234abc
12345abc
grep -P '^\d{4,}' input  #or grep -P '^[[:digit:]]{4,}' input 
1234abc
12345abc
```

Now I want to do this with awk,but the same regex is not working.

for example Following command does not give any output.

```
awk '/^[[:digit:]]{3,4}/' input 
awk '/^([[:digit:]]){3,4}/' input
```

I was expecting above command to print

```
123abc
1234abc
12345abc
```

**Note 1**: Currently I am using to define range but it is not sweet for big range.

```
awk '/^[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?/' input
```

**Note 2:**

```
awk --version |head -1
GNU Awk 3.1.7
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. GNU Awk 4.1.4 produces exactly your desired output.

Comment: In RHEL 5 and GNU awk 3.1.5, you must use the `--posix` option.

Comment: @Jdamian ,thanks, I was scratching my head from last few hours. .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `--posix` option.

In the man pages of awk version 3, you can read:

```
r{n,m}     One or two numbers inside braces denote an interval expression.  If there is one number in the braces, the preceding regu-
           lar  expression  r  is  repeated  n times.  If there are two numbers separated by a comma, r is repeated n to m times.  If
           there is one number followed by a comma, then r is repeated at least n times.
           Interval expressions are only available if either --posix or --re-interval is specified on the command line.
```

Comment: This is the manpage for AWK version 3 and earlier. In version 4 interval expressions are supported by default.

Comment: Don't do that, use `--re-interval` instead of `--posix` as the latter will disable gawk extensions like `gensub()`, but if you need this your aw version is about 20 years out of date and it's way past time to get a newer version.