# regex for capturing a number with a range of digits in AWK

Tags: regex, bash, awk

Im trying to capture numbers inside a file using AWK, I could capture all, but im not being able to capture those in a certain amount of digits. What im doing wrong?

`echo -e "$teste" | awk '/_OA/ { match($0,/\[\([:digit:]{4,13}\]/);oa = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);print oa}'`

File sample:

```
_OA ............. [6712227000168]
_OA Tasdsd, OA .. [91][355016]
_OA Tasdsd, DA .. [91][5512987000]
```

Expected:

```
6712227000168
355016
5512987000
```

Hint for the regex match answers:
Thanks so much for all the answers, i found [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40736070/character-class-range-in-awk-version-3-1-7) that I need to use a **--posix** option because of my awk version.

Comment: What's the expected output when the length of a digit sequence is greater than 13? Will that sequence be discarded entirely? Or, will the first 13 digits be printed and remaining digits be discarded?

Comment: Hi M. Nejat Aydin. Everything outside the range should be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regexp `\[\([:digit:]{4,13}\]` says:

1. `\[` = the literal character `[`
2. `\(` = the literal character `(`
3. `[:digit:]` = a bracket expression containing a character set of the characters `:`, `d`, `i`, `g`, `t`
4. `{4,13}` = a regexp interval that's 4 to 13 repetitions of the preceding bracket expression
5. `\]` = the literal character `]`

The 2 main issues with that which are causing your regexp to be unable to match any of your input are:

1. You don't have any `(`s in your input (from #2 above), and
2. To match digits you need a character class `[:digit:]` inside a bracket expression `[[:digit:]]`, not a character set `:digit:` inside a bracket expression `[:digit:]` (from #3 above)

You also don't actually need to escape the `]` at the end of the regexp as it's only a regexp metachar (end of bracket expression) if preceded by a matching unescaped `[` (start of bracket expression).

So the regexp I think you wanted to write instead would have been:

```
\[[[:digit:]]{4,13}]
```

e.g.:

```
$ awk '/_OA/ { match($0,/\[[[:digit:]]{4,13}]/);oa = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);print oa}' file
[6712227000168]
[355016]
[5512987000]
```

or to only print the numbers:

```
$ awk '/_OA/ { match($0,/\[[[:digit:]]{4,13}]/);oa = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2);print oa}' file
6712227000168
355016
5512987000
```

Comment: Ive copied your command but im getting a empty output, i checked for hidden characters but found nothing. Do you know what can it be?

Comment: Maybe your version of awk doesn't support range expressions and/or character classes? Which OS are you on and which version of awk are you running?

Comment: What do you man by "empty output"? No output or output that's a series of blank lines, one per input line? You aren't trying to write the output back to the input file are you?

Comment: No, I'm printing on terminal. The output is a bunch of empty lines, one per input line. I'm using a Red Hat enterprise 6.6 and awk version 3.1.7.

Comment: Is that **GNU** awk 3.1.7? If so it's about 20 years out of date and missing a ton of new functionality and bug fixes, time to get a modern release! The accepted answer on that question you linked is wrong, you should add `--re-interval`, not `--posix` as the latter disables gawk extensions like `gensub()`.

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` solution. Simply making field separator as `]` OR `[` and in main block checking condition if line starts from `_QA`  then printing the 2nd last field.

```
awk -F"[][]" '/^_QA /{print $(NF-1)}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

You could update the pattern and the values for RSTART and RLENGTH to not match the leading and trailing square brackets.

The digits part should be `[[:digit:]]` and there is a `\(` in the pattern that matches `(` that should not be there.

```
awk '/_OA/ { match($0,/\[[[:digit:]]{4,13}\]/);oa = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2);print oa}' <<< "$teste"
```

Output

```
6712227000168
355016
5512987000
```

---

As there are multiple occurrences of digits between square brackets, if you want to match multiple occurrences:

```
teste='_OA Tasdsd, OA .. [91][355016][123456789][1][9999]'

awk '/_OA/ {
  while(match($0,/\[[[:digit:]]{4,13}]/)){
    start=RSTART+1; len=RLENGTH-2
    s=substr($0,start,len)
    res=res?res","s:s    
    $0=substr($0,start+len)
  }
  print res
  res = ""
}' <<< "$teste"
```

Output

```
355016,123456789,9999
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not married to awk:

```bash
grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{4,13}'
```

With GNU awk:

```bash
gawk 'match($0, /[[:digit:]]{4,13}/, m) {print m[0]}'
```

but that only matches the first such number in each record. To find them all:

```bash
gawk '{
    line = $0
    while (match(line, /[[:digit:]]{4,13}/, m)) {
        print m[0]
        line = substr(line, m[0,"start"] + m[0,"length"])
    }
}'
```

Ref the [`match` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-match_0028_0029-function) in the gawk manual.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```bash
awk '/_OA/ { match($0,/\[[[:digit:]]{4,13}]/);print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)}'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/uaK8hX):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='_OA ............. [6712227000168]
_OA Tasdsd, OA .. [91][355016]
_OA Tasdsd, DA .. [91][5512987000]'
awk '/_OA/ { match($0,/\[[[:digit:]]{4,13}]/);print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)}' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
6712227000168
355016
5512987000
```

**Details**:

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[[:digit:]]{4,13}` - four to thirteen digits (note that the `[:digit:]` POSIX character class must be used within `[...]`, a bracket expression)
- `]`  - a `]` char (it is not special, no need escaping)

And `substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)` means that we

- `$0` - take the match
- `RSTART+1` - starting with the second char
- `RLENGTH-2` - and then as many characters as is the match length - 2 (thus getting rid of enclosing `[` and `]` chars)

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. I copied exactly what youve done but im getting a empty output, i checked for hidden characters but found nothing. Do you know what can it be?

Comment: @LuizBom I do not see where the issue is since [my demo proves it's working as is](https://ideone.com/uaK8hX).